# What is the solution to NextJs Error: "Title element received an array with more than 1 element as children."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Creating a component to wrap every page with the hope of receiving children and title for each page is throwing error. "Title element received an array with more than 1 element as children."

```
import Head from "next/head";

interface IProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
  title?: string;
  restProps?: any;
}
export default function MetaDataContainer(props: IProps) {
  const {
    children,
    title = "Generated by create next app",
    ...restProps
  } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>CV-stack - {title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to provide an object like so

```
<title>{`CV-stack - ${title}`}</title>
```

Because of the reasons explained in this comment (react dom string rendering) https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38256

Answer (score 2):

I saw a solution online on [this link](https://modthefuture.com/fix-next-js-title-element-received-warning-react/).

Below is the sample code that works:

```js
import Head from "next/head";

interface IProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
  title?: string;
  restProps?: any;
}
export default function MetaDataContainer(props: IProps) {
  const {
    children,
    title = "Generated by create next app",
    ...restProps
  } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{`CV-stack - ${title}`}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Notice that the title is now a single node with {`CV-stack - ${title}`} instead of CV-stack - {title}

Answer (score 1):

if your pulling it from your .env file, then you should use it like this:

```
const website_title = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBSITE_TITLE;

 <Head>
     <title>{`${website_title}`}</title>
     <link rel="icon" href={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBSITE_FAVICON} />
      <meta
      name="description"
      content={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBSITE_META}
      />
 </Head>
```